# ffmpeg - divide video into 2 pieces

Tags: video, ffmpeg, clipping

Is it possible to visually split video into 2 pieces using ffmpeg? I have many videos which have to be splitted into 2 videos which first is clipped to 50% of width and second from 50% to the end.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Sark's solution works, but here are a couple single-command alternatives that you can try.

First, you can combine these 2 runs into 1 (saving demuxing time):

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf crop=w=iw/2:h=ih:0:0 output1 \
                -vf crop=w=iw/2:h=ih:iw/2:0 output2
```

Second, if frames need to be exactly halved, you can use `untile` followed by `select`:

```
ffmpeg -i input \
       -filter_complex untile=2x1,select=mod(n\\\\,2)+1[vout1][vout2]
       -map [vout1] output1 \
       -map [vout2] output2
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply two crops as follows.

```
    ffmpeg -i input -vf crop=w=iw/2:h=ih:0:0 output1

    ffmpeg -i input -vf crop=w=iw/2:h=ih:iw/2:0 output2
```

You can do this in one script.